# set textbox value with razor only uses numeric portion

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am setting the value "30 Day Report" to

```
<input type="text" value=@Model.rpt.ReportDescription.ToString() />
```

But the value ends up being only "30".  I verified this using chrome developer tools.  It works if I use @Html.TextBox() or @Html.TextBoxFor() so I know the value comes through, but I don't want to use any html helpers. How can I make the value display properly without html helpers?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the quotes `"` around the value:

```
<input type="text" value="@Model.rpt.ReportDescription.ToString()" />
//                       ^                                       ^
```

Comment: Thank you!  I knew it had to be something simple I missed.